# Create HTML table in a Java Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

Using a java servlet, I've been doing the same approach to building or updating HTML.  I create the basic table on the HTML page, then call for the body from the servlet with ajax.

As an example:
HTML

```
    <div id="divLocationMain" style="margin-top: 2%;">
        <table style="width: 99%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Clinic</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Clinic</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbodyAdminLocation" style="font-size: small;">

            </tbody>
        </table> 
    </div>
```

javascript

```
function updateLocationTable() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'TCAUServlet',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {formType: "getLocationTable"},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (responseText) {
            $('#tbodyAdminLocation').html('');
            $('#tbodyAdminLocation').html(responseText);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert("An error occurred.  Error:  " + status + ", " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Servlet

```
private String getLocationTable() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    List<Location> locList = TCAUDatabaseUtil.getLocations();
    Collections.sort(locList, new LocationComparator());
    String htmlString = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < locList.size(); x++) {
        Location loc = locList.get(x);
        htmlString += "                                    <tr>\n"
                + "                                        <td>" + loc.getLocationClinic() + "</td>\n"
                + "                                        <td>" + loc.getLocationName() + "</td>\n";
        if (x < locList.size() - 1) {
            loc = locList.get(++x);
            htmlString += "                                    <td>" + loc.getLocationClinic() + "</td>\n"
                    + "                                        <td>" + loc.getLocationName() + "</td>\n";
        }
        htmlString += "                                    </tr>\n";
    }
    return htmlString;
}
```

It works well, but I can't help but wonder if there isn't a better/easier/more efficient way, especially when I'm dealing with objects with quite a few fields in them.

Comment: `$('#tbodyAdminLocation').html('');` is redundant as `html(content)` will replace the _innerHTML_ of element, there is no need to first empty it. In Java, no need to add spaces just to indent the code in `htmlString`. `\n` has no effect(just adds space) in DOM thus, can be removed.

Comment: @Tushar:  Agreed, but it makes it easier to read if I need to do troubleshooting.  And agreed about the redundant clearing of the old tbody.  .

Comment: You can use a StringBuffer instead of all those concatenations. Maybe can you create an 'HtmlTable' class to hide the string création. And/Or use a Dom library. For the jQuery part, I have the feeling that there is a 'load' function to do that.